# How to make the first n words more important in Lucene

Tags: lucene

I want to make the first n (which i set) words from a document more important that the rest of the document in Lucene. How will i do that? I found something about boosting, but boost a field to be more important. My document is supposed to be an only field. 
Is to number the words at indexing time and boost them a solution? Something like that:

```
TextField myField = new TextField("text",termAtt.toString(),Store.YES);

myField.setBoost(2);

document.add(myField);
```

if the i didn't reach the n-th word in my document?
I want to get the following result: let's say that the first 20 words in a document are more important than the rest. I have 2 identical documents that have more than 20 words and i add the word that i am searching in one document as th first word and in the second document as the last word, an i want that the first document to have a bigger score.

Answer (score 3):

The best approach would be to simply create two different fields, one containing the higher value portion of the text (this wouldn't need to be stored), and the next containing the full text:

```java
int leadinLength = 20
TextField myFieldLeadin = new TextField("text_leadin",termAtt.toString().substring(leadinLength,Store.NO);
TextField myField = new TextField("text, termAtt.toString(),Store.YES);
myFieldLeadin.setBoost(2);
document.add(myFieldLeadin);
document.add(myField);
```

To could use a [`MultiFieldQueryParser`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_8_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/MultiFieldQueryParser.html) to streamline searching in both fields at once, if desired, like:

```java
Query query = MultiFieldQueryParser.parse(Version.LUCENE_48, "my search query",{"text_leadin","text"}, analyzer);
TopDocs docs = searcher.search(query, 10);
```

Comment: The problem with this is that if you have 21 words, and the search matches the first and last words, then the document with the last word will have a higher score, as a field of 1 value with no boost is more important then a field with 20 boosted values

Comment: @AlexandruSeverin - No, the "text" field, in the example code I've given, would have 21 terms, not 1.  The first 20 terms would be present in both fields.

Comment: Oooh, thank you, I've spent too much time trying to fix the balance between scores

Comment: But If I would have two identical documents, with an unique word added on 1st position(in doc1) and on 21th position(doc2), then reduce the boost to 1, then doc1's score would still be higher then 2nd, as it would match the words twice (in both fields), is there any way balance this?

Comment: Remove the boost, or tweak it to an appropriate level, that sort of thing.  If you really need to micro-manage scoring, though, you might need to look into implementing a custom similarity eventually.